# Installing VMware Player on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, debian, installation

I want to install VMware Player on Ubuntu 9.04. The official VMware download page does not have a `deb` package. Should I use their RPM? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VMWare Player installation on Ubuntu is much different than VMWare Server.  It's entirely painless, and many less steps.
Download the '.bundle' version for Linux after registering on the VMWare website.
Save .bundle file to your desktop (or where ever).  From a command prompt, run:

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-2.5.1-126130.i386.bundle
```

and follow the on screen installation wizard (it's pretty straight forward - I don't think you need to install/compile any additional components with Ubuntu 9.04 - it's currently supported out of the box).

Comment: Thanks!  While they list it as 'experimental' support, it has been working fine for me since 9.04 came out.

Answer (score 1):

For installing VMWare Server on Debian/Lenny you need to use the .tgz download. There are a few recipes for the procedure, including [this one that I happen to have bookmarked](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vmware-server-2-on-debian-lenny). The procedure for Ubuntu should be similar, if not identical, and the procedure for Player (rather than Server) should be similarly similar.

Edit: there are in fact [instructions for VMWare Server install on Ubuntu 9.04 on howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vmware-server-2-on-ubuntu-9.04) too. None specific to Player though.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, I had the same problem! After some research I verify that the right command is "sudo sh " + "name of the packet".bundle

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call `sh`. You can simply make the downloaded file executable by using `chmod +x yourfile`, and then run the file normally by calling `./yourfile`.